# Visual Studio hangs when remote debugging a Cordova iOS app

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, remote-debugging, visual-studio-cordova

I use Visual Studio 2013 with 'Tools for Apache Cordova'. In the settings page 'Remote Agent Configuration' of the Cordova tools, I enabled the iOS remote processing.

During remote debugging of an iOS Cordova app, Visual Studio hangs when I set a breakpoint to inspect a result of a cordova plugin. I then need to restart Visual Studio.

A breakpoint on a line which is executed before calling a Cordova plugin works without problems... Also storing the result of a Cordova plugin in a variable and then inspecting it using another click event handler works.

Does someone else also notice this problem? Could you fix it?

Comment: It would be useful to know more specifics. Could you share a code snippet and more info about the plugin you are using?   Does it also happen if you build and deploy to Android or WinPhone with the same plugin?  Does it happen with other plugins?

Comment: What is the plugin? Do other plugins cause same issue?

Comment: I use the cordova file plugin and 2 self written plugins. There is the same issue for all of them. In the following article, Rick says that it he could use debugging without problems: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Jan/06/Using-Cordova-and-Visual-Studio-to-build-iOS-Mobile-Apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with self-written plugins.

Try to let your plugin run in a background thread. Then debugging should work without problems. Look at the following code snippet:

```
- (void)myMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
       NSString* callbackId = command.callbackId;

       [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
             // your plugin logic comes here

             // successful plugin execution
             CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"success"];
             [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:callbackId];
       }

       return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot hirtenfelder. That solves the debugging problem of my self-written plugins. But with the Cordova file plugin I have still the same problem...